# How to get the size of a list in java?

Tags: angularjs, spring

### UserController

```
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private Object model;


  @GetMapping("/user/all")
    public List<User> getUsers(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("countUsers", userRepository.countUsers());
        return userService.getUsers();
    }
```

Please help me...Give me some idea..to write a query for count total users in spring boot and angular

Comment: the question has nothing to do with spring boot or angular, it seems the user was interested just for the size of a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new mapping for return count and call it through angular.

```
@GetMapping("/user/getCount")
public List<User> getCount(Model model){ 
    return getUsers(model).size()
}
```